# I am trying to unmarshall the following yaml into the below structs, how do I convert the List field into a map field and access it using struct?

Tags: go, struct, hashmap, yaml, unmarshalling

The YAML file:

```yaml
namespaces:
  - namespace: default
    aliasname: k8s
    components:
      - component: comp1
        replicas: 1
        port: 8080
      - component: comp2
        replicas: 1
        port: 9999
  - namespace: ns2
    components:
      - component: comp1
        replicas: 1
```

From the YAML file above, I want to create structs like the following:

```golang
type Namespaces struct {
    NamespaceName    string       `yaml:"namespace"`
    Aliasname     string       `yaml:"aliasname,omitempty"`
    ListOfComponents []Components `yaml:"components"`
    ComponentMap     map[string]Components

}

type Components struct {
    ComponentName string `yaml:"component"`
    NumReplicas   int    `yaml:"replicas"`
    Port          int    `yaml:"port"`
}

type Config struct {
    ListOfNamespaces []Namespaces `yaml:"namespaces"`
    NamespaceMap map[string]Namespaces
}
```

The fields `Namespacemap` and `Componentmap` should be able to be retrieved when accessing the `config` and `namespace` object respectively. I created a method to convert the list of the namespaces and components into maps, but when I call `config.Namespacemap` or `Namespace.ComponentMap`, it returns an empty map.

Basically I would like to know: How do we add extra fields to type structs? I would like to access new variables like a map from the `config` struct.

**Update:**
Thanks blami for guiding me, but when I try to write the same for Components, it doesn't give me the whole namespacemap with the componentmap included:

```
type Components struct {
    ComponentName string `yaml:"component"`
    NumReplicas   int    `yaml:"replicas"`
    Port          int    `yaml:"port"`

}

type Namespaces struct {
    NamespaceName string                `yaml:"namespace"`
    Aliasname  string                `yaml:"aliasname"`
    ComponentMap  map[string]Components `yaml:"components"`
}

func (n *Namespaces) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {

    type origNamespace struct {
        ListOfComponents []Components `yaml:"components"`
    }

    var on origNamespace
    err1 := unmarshal(&on)
    if err1 != nil {
        return err1
    }
    n.ComponentMap = make(map[string]Components)
    for _, i := range on.ListOfComponents {
        n.ComponentMap[i.ComponentName] = i
    }

    return nil
}
```

When I run the config.NamespaceMap it gives the following

```
map[:{NamespaceName: K8sNamespace: ComponentMap:map[comp1:{ComponentName:comp1 NumShards:0 NumReplicas:1 Port:0 EpochLength:0}]}]
```

Comment: Please consider fixing the question. "I am trying to unmarshall the following yaml into a struct that has an extra field map that I can access along with the struct?" doesn't look like a sentence to me.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question let me know if I need to further edit it.

Comment: Can you include the code/method you reference in the question

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do such transformation you will need to write a customized [`UnmarshalYAML()`](https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Unmarshaler) receiver on types `Config` and `Namespace`. Here is basic working example of doing so (only for "namespaces"):

```golang
type Config struct {
    Namespaces map[string]Namespace `yaml:"namespaces"`
}

// Replace go-yaml built-in unmarshaller with custom that will transform list to map.
// Note this code is meant only as demonstration!
func (c *Config) UnmarshalYAML(unmarshal func(interface{}) error) error {
    type origConfig struct {
        Namespaces []Namespace `yaml:"namespaces"`
    }
    var o origConfig
    err := unmarshal(&o)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // Assign namespaces in list to map; namespaces with same name will be overwritten
    c.Namespaces = make(map[string]Namespace)
    for _, n := range o.Namespaces {
        c.Namespaces[n.Namespace] = n
    }
    return nil
}

// You can use "Config" type as usual
func main() {
    var config Config
    err := yaml.Unmarshal(<your_yaml>, &config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(config.Namespaces)
    // map[default:{default k8s} ns2:{ns2 }]
    fmt.Printf("%v\n", config.Namespaces["default"])
    // {default k8s}
}
```

As noted in code example this will cause some problems (e.g. what to do if namespace names are same?).

Playground link: https://go.dev/play/p/IKg8kmRnknq

Comment: Thank you, this is what I wanted, let me add it for component too, also is this the standard way? Since I am new to golang I just want to know if this is the standard approach, but this definitely is the answer to my question.

Comment: Using custom `UnmarshalYAML()` receiver for custom types that do not follow YAML structure is pretty much standard approach that is modeled after standard library `json` package. Although most projects I saw just try to stick with original YAML/JSON structure - in this case list of namespaces unless really inconvenient.

Comment: Can you please look at the update @blami

Comment: @Niharika your code only looks at Components field. When you override UnmarshalYAML() receiver you are responsible for everything. So you need to handle all fields. Also there's a slight BUG in code that it creates new components map for each component which will override previous components. I added fixed code to https://go.dev/play/p/Boq_2Kku8-C . As you can see maintaining these maps can become tedious and error prone - so that's why it is better to stick with whatever original file structure is.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the corrections, I was banging my head why I was getting an empty namespacemap, yes I understand the bug I had. Let me try to see if I can actually stick to the original yaml file.

Comment: I am trying to set the default namespace @blami and to be overwritten for every namespace. So I am planning to use viper for that , any suggestions on that..

Comment: Does viper.unmarshal resolve to unmershalYAML

Comment: @Niharika sorry I do not have any experience with viper (never had to use that library). Also that changes question significantly and its likely answer would be convoluted. IMO would be better to start new question for that.